# Await behaviour within an async IIFE

Tags: javascript, async-await

I was trying to understand the behaviour of `async/await` and came up with this example

```js
function foo() {
  async function bar() {
    return new Promise((resolve)=> {
      setTimeout(()=> {
        resolve("Done");
      }, 1);
    });
  }

  (async function () {
    console.log("Calling bar...");
    const res = await bar();
    console.log("After bar...");
  })();
}
console.log("Calling foo...");
foo();
console.log("After foo...");
```

I was expecting the output to be

```
Calling foo...
Calling bar...
After bar...
After foo...
```

whereas the output is

```
Calling foo...
Calling bar...
After foo...
After bar...
```

Why doesn't the script execution wait on the `const res = await bar();` statement but instead execute the `console.log("After foo...");`? Does the `await` inside an anonymous block lead to the *deferral* of the `async` code block somehow?

One way I tried to reason about this was that since `await` is built upon `promise`, it essentially changes the code to something like

```js
function foo() {
  async function bar() {
    return new Promise((resolve)=> {
      setTimeout(()=> {
        resolve("Done");
      }, 1);
    });
  }

  (async function () {
    console.log("Calling bar...");
    const res = bar();
    res.then(() => {
      console.log("After bar...");
    });
  })();
}
console.log("Calling foo...");
foo();
console.log("After foo...");
```

which would possibly explain why the `console.log("After bar...");` is executed *after* the `console.log("After foo...");` statement. Is that the right way to reason about this or is there something that I'm missing here?

Comment: That is the correct way to think about it.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the await inside an anonymous block lead to the deferral of the async code block somehow?

Yes.

```js
function takeOneTick(){
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>setTimeout(resolve));
}

async function foo(){
  console.log("1");
  await takeOneTick();
  console.log("3");
}

foo();
console.log("2");
```

Every async function returns a Promise. If you need the code to execute in order, then you await your async function.

```js
function takeOneTick(){
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>setTimeout(resolve));
}

async function foo(){
  console.log("1");
  await takeOneTick();
  console.log("2");
}

(async function(){
  await foo();
  console.log("3");
})();
```

Also, Returning a Promise from an async function is a Promise in a Promise (which won't do anything bad but there is no point).

Also Also, yes `await` is like putting the remainder of the function in a `.then()`